# My Propertgrid Repeats on every controls click present on to the form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I click on any control in my form or usercontrol then propertygrid shows but it repeats for each control on to the form. How can I show only once for each control click

```
public void Selectpropertygrid()
{            
    foreach (Control c in dock_Control1.Controls)
    {
        c.MouseClick+=new MouseEventHandler(c_MouseClick);
    }
    foreach (Control ctr in this.Controls)
    {
        ctr.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(c_MouseClick);
    }
 }
 
 public void c_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {   
     Control ct=sender as Control;
     prp = new PropertyGrid();
     prp.CommandsVisibleIfAvailable = true;
     prp.Location = new Point(0, 0);
     prp.Size = new Size(220 ,800);      
     prp.Enabled = true;            
     prp.Visible = true;
     prp.Text = "Properties";
     prp.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
     prp.Enabled = true;
     this.Controls.Add(prp);            
     prp.SelectedObject = ct;           
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite likely that you've got multiple event subscriptions to the `c_MouseClick` event handler. It is preferable, if not advisable to remove any event handler before adding the desired one.

Try modifying your code to something like this and see if it is fixed.

```
public void Selectpropertygrid()
{            
    foreach (Control c in dock_Control1.Controls)
    {
        c.MouseClick -= c_MouseClick;
        c.MouseClick += c_MouseClick;
    }
    foreach (Control ctr in this.Controls)
    {
        ctr.MouseClick -= c_MouseClick;
        ctr.MouseClick += c_MouseClick;
    }
 }
```

Comment: even I suggested the same thing, but he is looking for some thing else I believe

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure or clear about your scenario. But as far as I understand for every UserControl or Control, you must be having an event attached to it. So at the end of the event, remove (-=) that event from the control by using the 'sender' parameter. try to give some more information so that I can clearly mention what I am saying.

```
(sender as Control).Click -= event();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: see on every controls click if its in usercontrol or in form ...the propertygrid shows but it appends to previously control clicks...                                                              if ButtonA and ButtonB is present in Form and if i clicked on ButtonA then it shows propertgrid and then click on ButtonB then Propertgrid shows of ButtonB but ButtonA propertygrid appends with ButtonB..........its same thing happens for other controls...append append apend ......:)

Comment: ok....in that case, you need must have just cleared the propertygrid everytime you click a control.

Comment: @noah1989 Look at NMD's second comment on this answer.

Comment: public void c_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {   if(prp!=null)
      { //////}  
 }

Comment: thanks for your solution, but try adding it to the question in more proper way